# What CMD command will generate an error iff a file is empty or absent?

Tags: cmd, windows-7

... such that I can write e.g.

```
thatcommand myfile.txt && ECHO Is non-empty || ECHO Is empty or absent
```

(To the form processor: this does completely describe the problem.)

Comment: If a file exists and has a size greater than 0 bytes then it is non-empty else it is empty or absent. Search and try commands which check file size and return here editing your question with your code attempts and relevant explanations if your own code fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To limit it to only one command with the same approach in your code, you can try with

```dos
(>nul 2>nul findstr /m "^" "myfile.txt") && echo ok || echo empty or absent
```

This code uses `findstr` to check file contents against a regular expression matching anything and returning only the file name (leaving the search on the first match)

- If the file exist and it is not empty, the regular expression will find a match. Command clears the `errorlevel`
- If the file is empty, there is not any possible match and the command
  sets `errorlevel` to `1`
- If the file does not exist, the command directly fails (file not found) and `errorlevel` is set to `1`

Comment: Thanks. If you'd be so kind as to post these two answers as two answers, I'll accept one.

Comment: @ChrisJJ, No problem, the two options in original answer are now two different answers.

Comment: Thanks PS Related Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085095/whats-the-benefit-of-the-brackets-here

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed by Compo, a check for the file size is probably the better way of handling it. One option could be

```dos
for %%a in ("myfile.txt") do if "%%~za" gtr "0" ( echo ok ) else (echo empty or absent )
```

- If the file is present, its size is checked against `0` (note: string compare operations are used to avoid problems with sizes greater than 2<sup>31</sup>).
- If the file is not present, the `~z` modifier will return an empty string that is alphabetically lower than `"0"`

Comment: Downvoting. It doesn't answer the question. Note the "e.g.".

Comment: @ChrisJJ, Sure, this does not answer the question in the exposed terms, but I had to include it because this approach is much faster.