# What's the benefit of the brackets here?

Tags: cmd, windows-7

Code:

```
 (>nul 2>nul findstr /m "^" "myfile.txt") && echo ok || echo empty or absent
```

I asked because this:

```
 >nul 2>nul findstr /m "^" "myfile.txt" && echo ok || echo empty or absent
```

appears equivalent.

Comment: I would assume programmers preference, if I were to use them I'd use either, `FindStr/M "^" "myfile.txt">Nul 2>&1&&(Echo ok)||Echo empty or absent` or more likely, `(FindStr/M "^" "myfile.txt")>Nul 2>&1&&Echo ok||Echo empty or absent`.

Comment: As usual, Compo is right. The code does not need the parenthesis, but with them in place it is easier to read, separating command and the success/failure handling and stating where the redirection is applied. Spaces around the `&& ||` operators (e.g.) are also not needed (and yes, sometimes they are undesirable), but they also make the code in the answer more readable.